# jQuery trigger SVG animation can only work once

Tags: jquery, svg

I use jQuery `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event to trigger zoom in and zoom out animation for SVG. It seems that the `mouseleave` event works fine, but the `mouseenter` event can only works once.

http://jsbin.com/IZAYAWU/1/edit

Is there anything I did wrong? How can I make it work normal? Thank you!

PS. The reason that I don't use CSS `transform: scale()` is because it will bing blurry effect in webkit browsers, and I've tried many ways but still can't fix it.

Comment: Looks like a bug in webkit, have you reported it? You can avoid using script completely, see http://jsbin.com/IZAYAWU/4/edit, though the mouseenter bug is still visible.

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't realise it works normal in Firefox. It looks like a bug. I'll report it.